# cloud sms services that could buy local numbers and map them together

Tags: sms, cloud, sms-gateway

Hi I want to achieve this. Do you know a service that would allow me to do this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com) (or a similar SMS API), to purchase and proxy through the virtual numbers.

Here's [some example code](https://github.com/Nexmo/Proxy) - the specific use case for the example is a situation where you want to *mask* the user's phone numbers; however, the same concept applies to what you want to do.

And here's a more high level implementation guide on [proxying SMS through virtual numbers](http://nexmo.github.io/Proxy/) (or direct [to the Prezi](http://prezi.com/1gs_qvnegmgn/how-to-proxy-sms-with-audio/)).

*Disclaimer: I do some developer evangelism for Nexmo.*

Comment: hi thank you for responding, do you have a much more comprehensive `guide` than just the code itself?

Comment: @bman Not at this point. I'll update the answer if / when we do.

Comment: @bman Code updated with a bit more documentation, as well as a Prezi showing the implementation.